# Reduce SVG repetition / footprint on server response

Tags: html, svg

Say i have this HTML layout:

```
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-image">
    <h3 class="card-title">...</h3>
    <p class="card-text">...</p>
    <a class="card-link">
      text
      <svg class="card-link-svg">
        ...some svg
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    ...
  </div>

  ...
</div>
```

Which is a card repeated say 20 times on a page for examples sake.

In the response from the server i have the same SVG code repeated 20 times. Then i if multiply this by 4 ~ 5 to represent other card sets i now have the same SVG code ~100 times repeated over and over.

I then have say another ~20-30 varying SVG's of different sizes and shapes that are used in other components on the page, making it hard to get in to a sprite sheet.

On one of my pages on my site this has bloated my initial response up to `220kb` just for the document, which to me is quite huge.

Is there a way to reduce the code footprint of using SVG's while maintaining the ability to style them with CSS?

Comment: Which parts of the duplicated svgs (`.card-link-svg`) need to be customized/styled individually with CSS?

Comment: In this instance they don't, they all have the same style but the `arrow.svg` has many different colours / styles, as well as other SVG's on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-with-external-reference-take-2/) combined with [this](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) seems to have been what i was after.

**/static/svg/sprite.svg**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <symbol id="arrow" viewBox="214.7 0 182.6 792">
    <!-- <path>s and whatever other shapes in here -->  
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="shape-icon-2" viewBox="0 26 100 48">
    <!-- <path>s and whatever other shapes in here -->  
  </symbol>

</svg>
```

Allows external reference to a singular SVG so it boils down to:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="/static/svg/sprite.svg#arrow"></use>
</svg>
```